# ngOnInit life cycle hook behaviour with routing module?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using following routes in my app's root routing module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeDetailsComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeDetailsComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'room/:id', 
            component: RoomDetailsComponent,
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'sectorNumber',
        component: SectorNumberComponent
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: 'home',
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

Now, inside HomeDetailsComponent, I am using OnInit life cycle hook to call an http get method and based on that, do some event handling. However, I noticed that with this kind of routing, my HomeDetailsComponent is getting initialised twice. Once when I navigate to `'http://localhost:3000/#/curriculum/'` and second when I navigate to `'http://localhost:3000/#/curriculum/chapter/1'` route. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Because the component is not reused for different routes. The component from the route where you navigate away will be destroyed and the one where you navigate to, will be created. This is only different when the from-route and to-route are the same but a parameter value (`:id`) changed.

Comment: If from-route and to-route are the same but a parameter value (:id) changed then it will not reinitialise, is that what you mean ?

Comment: Exactly . . . .

Comment: Because I tried the same and it is reinitialising in that case as well. I am going from 'xxx/home' to 'xxx/home/2' and can see it reinitialising.

Comment: But that are two different routes, one without a parameter, and one with a parameter. You have to configure two routes, to even be able to do that.